# Consolidating redundant parameters in requests

Tags: python, request, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm using the requests module in my code (obviously to do requests), and my code is quickly getting out of hand because of redundant parameters that I need to include for each request:

```
def one(url, data, headers, cert):
    ...
    return requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, verify=cert)

def two(otherurl, otherheaders, cert):
    ...
    response = requests.get(otherurl, headers=otherheaders, verify=cert).json()
```

Is there a way to tell every request to use `verify=cert` without having to include it within every request statement? I'm thinking `session()` should be able to do this, although I have no idea how to use it. I'm just trying to minimize the repeating of things that maybe could be set globally within my script. Maybe this is not possible or how it actually works? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.partial` to override these functions with `verify=cert` passed as an argument by default:

```
from functools import partial
requests.post = partial(requests.post, verify=cert)
requests.get = partial(requests.get, verify=cert)
```

Or if you look at the source code of `requests`, you'll find that both of these two functions are simply wrappers to the `requests.request` function, which in turn is a wrapper to the `requests.Session.request` method. You can therefore override `requests.Session.request` instead to have all the HTTP methods overridden with one statement. Since it's a method and not an unbound function, however, you have to use `functools.partialmethod` instead:

```
from functools import partialmethod
requests.Session.request = partialmethod(requests.Session.request, verify=cert)
```

Comment: Hi, on the second example I get `TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. I'm probably doing something wrong - first example works fine - thanks!

Comment: You might want to update the question with how you use `partial` in your code so that I or others can better help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I just started using it after you mentioned it.

Comment: I mean, you can post how you use it in your code so we have better context.

Comment: I went ahead and posted a working example of the code [here](https://repl.it/repls/SmartQuirkyPrinter).

Comment: I see. I forgot that `functools.partial` doesn't work on bound methods. For methods you have to use `functools.partialmethod` instead. I've updated my answer accordingly. You can also view the fix to your code here: https://repl.it/repls/SquareMicroSandbox